# Search large file to see if a sentence with missing words can be found

Tags: python, python-re

This is my current code, I have the `message_list` (the input) and the book (3686 lines) and need to check if the book contains the message. But the message has gaps, `"_"`, and a gap equals a word. But I don't know how to parse this into my `re` arguments. I have never worked with `re` before and that was my try on this.

```
message_list = ["das", "_", "mir", "_", "_", "_", "vor"]
book = readfile("Book.txt", False)
print(re.search(rf"\^{message_list[0]}\.\${message_list[len(message_list)-1]}", str(book)))
```

Book (*Alice in Wonderland* in German):

```
So fingen sie denn an, feierlich im Kreise um Alice zu tanzen; zuweilen
traten sie ihr auf die Füße, wenn sie ihr zu nahe kamen; die falsche
Schildkröte sang dazu, sehr langsam und traurig, Folgendes: --

Zu der Schnecke sprach ein Weißfisch: »Kannst du denn nicht
        schneller gehn?
    Siehst du denn nicht die Schildkröten und die Hummer
        alle stehn?
    Hinter uns da kommt ein Meerschwein, und es tritt mir auf
        den Schwanz;
    Und sie warten an dem Strande, daß wir kommen zu
        dem Tanz.
    Willst du denn nicht, willst du denn nicht, willst du kommen
        zu dem Tanz?
    Willst du denn nicht, willst du denn nicht, willst du kommen
        zu dem Tanz?«

 »Nein, du kannst es nicht ermessen, wie so herrlich es wird sein,
    Nehmen sie uns mit den Hummern, werfen uns in's Meer hinein!«
    Doch die Schnecke thät nicht trauen. »Das gefällt mir doch nicht ganz!
    Viel zu weit, zu weit! ich danke -- gehe nicht mit euch zum Tanz!
    Nein, ich kann, ich mag, ich will nicht, kann nicht kommen zu dem Tanz!
    Nein, ich kann, ich mag, ich will nicht, mag nicht kommen zu dem Tanz!«

 Und der Weißfisch sprach dagegen: »'s kommt ja nicht drauf an, wie
        weit!
    Ist doch wohl ein andres Ufer, drüben auf der andern Seit'!
    Und noch viele schöne Küsten giebt es außer Engelland's;
    Nur nicht blöde, liebe Schnecke, komm' geschwind mit mir zum Tanz!
    Willst du denn nicht, willst du denn nicht, willst du kommen zu dem
        Tanz?
    Willst du denn nicht, willst du denn nicht, willst nicht kommen zu dem
        Tanz?«
```

Excpected Output:

```
["das","_","mir","_","_","_","vor"]
Line 127 : ...
Line 256 : ...
```

and so on.

Comment: Add more details to the question; Like a view on `book`, what is exactly your input and expected output.

Comment: Which lines are lines 127 and 256?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The lines in the outpout are just random exampels

Comment: Okay and in this *concrete* example what should be the actual exact output?

Comment: Line 5780 : das was mir von dir zu vor - Would be an Output

Comment: That's not even in the input text, how can it be in the output?

Comment: The input is over 3000 lines long and i didn't want to add 3000 lines in here, this is just a small part of the input, the message could also be "Ist", "_", "wohl", "_" ,"andres","Ufer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the underscores can represent one word, then you can change them from underscores into a "single word match", which you can then make optional or multiple as required, in constructing a regular expression to match against the text. You just have to be careful about spaces, since there's normally a single space between words but the pattern also captures spaces, so  `*` can be useful, as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                                                                        
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                                                                                                                                      

import re

book = """icht, kann nicht kommen zu dem Tanz!                                                                                                                                               
  Nehmen sie uns mit den Hummern, werfen uns in's Meer hinein!«                                                                                                                              
    Doch die Schnecke thät nicht trauen. »Das gefällt mir doch nicht ganz!                                                                                                                   
    Viel zu weit, zu weit! ich danke -- gehe nicht mit euch zum Tanz!                                                                                                                        
    foo das foo mir bar one two vor foo                                                                                                                                                      
    Nein, ich kann, ich mag, ich will nicht, kann nicht kommen                                                                                                                               
    Nein, ich kann, ich mag, ich will nicht, mag nicht kommen zu dem Tanz!«~"""

def word_capture_or_literal(w): # _ matches a single word
   return '(?:\s+\S+)' if w == "_" else " *" + w                                                                                                                

message_list = ["das","_","mir","_","_","_","vor"]
pattern = "".join(map(word_capture_or_literal, message_list))
result = re.search(pattern, book)

print(result)
```

Result, finding the words ok:

```
% python foo.py
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10cd73b28>
```

Comment: I have a Question, would it work with a message_list with special characters to? - Like this one ['ich', 'muß', '_', 'clara', '_'] , with ß ?

Comment: I'm sad to say I'm not used to working with non-ascii characters, but the utf declaration at the top takes care of a lot, and within the regular expression I used "space and then non-space" so special chars should be captured ok. However, things like double-dash might be counted as words in my naive example. The '(?:\s+\S+)' pattern that is used instead of _ might be need some refining for real-world usage.

Comment: Also with re you have to enable ascii usage via a modifier, so by default it should work ok with ß and friends.

Comment: Thank you very much, i modified your code a bit and used re.findall(...) for my purpose